# I can't find out why I can't access two functions

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, session, local-storage

I'm trying to save in local storage the information from input. But when I press on "Save" or "Load", it enters in the "if" but not in the functions $('#save').on('click',...) and $('#load')...

```
if (typeof (Storage) !== "undefined") {

    $('#save').on('click', function() {
        window.alert("storagecomp");
        $('input[type="text"]').each(function() {
            var id = $(this).attr('id');
            var value = $(this).val();
            localStorage.setItem(id, value); 
        });
    });

    $('#load').on('click', function () {

        window.alert("warnigclick");
        $('input[type="text"]').each(function () {
            var id = $(this).attr('id');
            var value = localStorage.getItem(id);
           $(this).val(value);
        });
    });
} else {
    window.alert("Não suporte do browser para o LocalStorage");
}
```

Here's the code that calls the javascript code above.

```
<div id="buttonsL">
   <button type="submit" id="buttonL" name="submit">Registar Oferta</button>
   <button  id="save" name="submitG">Save</button>
   <button  id="load"  name="fg" >Load</button>
   <script  src="../JSFiles/LocalStorageStuff.js" language="Javascript"></script>
</div>
```

I've been searching all over but I can't figure out what I am doing wrong. Why isn't it accessing those two functions?

Comment: What is Storage ?is this present at the time of page load??

Comment: if those buttons are inside a form, they'll submit the form. you probably need to disable default events.

Comment: @Deep The if where "Storage" is, is to verify if the browser is compatible with the local storage

Answer (score 0):

Typos:

```
    $('input[type=text"]').each(function() {
                      ^---what's this for?
```

in both of your click handlers.

Comment: I guess he wanted to write `input[type="text"]`. So first quote is missing.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, it was indeed a typo, my bad. I fixed it immediately but it still doesn't enter them unfortunately